# How to install RPM package on Angstrom

Tags: package-management, rpm, angstrom

I'm using an embedded system with the Angstrom distribution on it. Now i'd like to configure a GPRS-Modem for it. So I downloaded the linux-driver from the homepage of the manufacterer to install it on my embedded system. But the package is a RPM-File, and the readme-file gives me the command:

```
rpm -ivv <packagename>
```

But there is no "rpm" command on my embedded-system (only opkg), and this isn't working for a rpm package.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you download a source RPM package or a tarball with sources?  From that you'll be able to create an opkg package.  The binary RPM is probably not going to be useful on this system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can download a debian package [this site](http://inportb.com/2010/10/19/making-an-opkg-package/) might help to build an opkg file from it.

If RPM is the only available format you might have success running that through [alien](http://www.howtoforge.com/converting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien) first.